# как найти в строке слова с заглавными буквами?

Tags: php

В строке часто попадаются слова, написанные большими буквами . Как такие слова найти и привести в нижний регистр ?

Answer (score 1):

Сперва разбить строку на массив предложений, потом преобразовать каждое предложение в нижний регистр, извлечь из каждого предложения первую букву, преобразовать её в верхний регистр, добавить изменённую букву в начало предложения и преобразовать всё обратно в строку:

```
$str = 'В строке ЧаСто ПопаДаются слОва, написанные БОЛЬШИМИ буквами . Как такие слова найти и привести в нижний регистр ?';

echo preg_replace_callback(
    '~[А-ЯЁ].+?[!?.]~',
    function($m){
        $lower = mb_strtolower($m[0], 'UTF-8');
        $chars = preg_split('~~u', $lower, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
        $first_char = mb_strtoupper(array_shift($chars), 'UTF-8');
        array_unshift($chars, $first_char);
        return join($chars);
    },
    $str
);
```

Результат:

```
В строке часто попадаются слова, написанные большими буквами . Как такие слова найти и привести в нижний регистр ?
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$text = 'text TEXT TeXt';

$text = mb_strtolower($text);
```